# Returning single field with multiple results query (Codeigniter)

Tags: sql, codeigniter

I have a code in Codeigniter

```
$subscription_ids_result = $this->db->query("SELECT subscription_id FROM clients_notification_registry")->result_array();
```

which results in

I need a result like to save myself from looping

I tried this but no luck.

Comment: I don't get it that you said "save myself from looping" ? Did you mean that you just wanna get 1 result from your database ?

Comment: Make your question clear. so that we can help you with

Comment: Any chance you need `WHERE` clause at the end of your query?